# Ddos attack on small site with shared hosting

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

I was informed by my hosting service that my site is getting hammered. It's a tiny out of date portfolio site and I haven't made any enemies lately so I'm guessing this is random. Any tips for protecting against attacks in the future? Is there anything I can even do when using a small shared host? I have zero experience when it comes to security and generally deal more with front end issues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're being used to deny another service on that shared host.

Comment: Make sure that any frameworks or cms that you use is to date / patched. Older versions of a lot of the are buggy and can be exploited / attacked and perhaps as rimian said you could be used to disrupt other hosts and they found to were vulnerable.

Comment: @Doon good suggestion. This site is using an old CMS, time for an update. And/or maybe just dismantling the whole thing since I'm not actively looking for new work and the work that is on it is way out of date. My hosting service people recommending I look into caching.

Comment: Well the other thing to do is look at the traffic and see what it is and what is being called.  Might not actually be a DDOS, but someting like a picture got picked up by a search engine, and the hotlinked somewhere, or the like.  Without knowing what the traffic is, it is hard to protect against it, etc...